# When I using java preparedstatement how can I reuse my codes to different table while preventing SQL injection?

Tags: java, sql

For example I have two tables.

```
create table teacher(
  teacherNum varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  teacherName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  sex varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(teacherNum)
);


create table lesson(
  lessonNum varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  lessonName    varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  year  int NOT NULL,
  term varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  credit int NOT NULL,
  teacherNum    varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  beforeLessonNum varchar(5),
  PRIMARY KEY(lessonNum),
  foreign key (teacherNum) references teacher(teacherNum)
);
```

and I want to write an insert function whose signature like this

```
public void insert(String table,String ...values)
```

I know I may manage to do it with string connection but I also know it will raise the risk of SQL injection. So how can I write this function?

Comment: I'm not seeing a lot of opportunity for code reuse here. You have different table names, different column names, different numbers of columns...

Comment: Batter is to use different function for different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation is fine as long as you're **not** doing it with user-supplied values. So for instance, this is fine:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + (condition ? "teacher" : "lesson") + " ("/*...*/;
```

...because the strings you're combining are entirely under your control. Just be sure that you use the various `PreparedStatement` `setXyz` methods with the values you're feed into the function, which presumably come from a user.

---

That said, I'm frankly not seeing a lot of opportunity for code reuse here. You have different table names, different column names, a different number of columns... Also, you've shown the method as accepting `String ...values` — how are you supposed to know which values are for which columns? If you're requiring all columns, then the method signature shouldn't misleading the coder by suggesting that it can accept a different number of columns. And you have no way of knowing what type to apply to each value. In short: This is a design that just asks for trouble.

Now, you *could* have a base class that knows the table name and the names and types of its columns, and then have a generic `insert(Map<String,Object> values)` method on the base class. You'd then have two loops through the map: The first loop builds the SQL by getting each column name from the map, checking that it's valid for the table (throwing an exception if not), and adding it to the list of columns for the `INSERT`. Then you add a sufficient number of `?` for the `VALUES` part. The you prepare that statement, and loop again using the appropriate `setXyz` method to set each value. But at that point, you're reinventing the wheel. Instead, you should be looking at known, coded, tested, proven ORM solutions instead.

Comment: Using string-concatenation instead of parameterized values will often also be bad for performance, because most DBMS's will have to make a new execution plan for each variant of the query.

Comment: @popovitsj: Only if the queries differ. If you're doing string concat for a static set of columns and just using the common method to put in the table name, etc., you'll get the same query. But I'm thinking the OP really should be going a different direction here...